# Gnuplot reading file data of specific columns without plotting

Tags: gnuplot

I am new to Gnuplot and have some trouble. I want to read a file with 50 rows and 4 columns and print row 1+3 in a new document.
With

```
set print "name.txt"
print "# X Y"
do for [i=1:50]{
    print i, error[i]   
}
set print
```

I can do the printing, but how can i read a file? (I don't want to plot anything)

Comment: Do you want to have _row_ 1 and 3 or _column_ 1 and 3 in the new document?

Comment: right, i want to calcualte column 1 + column 3 for every row

Comment: so, does my answer solve your problem? Any response would be appreciated. Upvote=helpful, Accept=solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the manual and in the gnuplot console type `help table`. You can "plot" to a table. I already wrote the code when you were correcting your question. So, here you have 3 variations. So, you were apparently asking for the third one.

Write **column 1 and 3** into a new document:

```
set table 'myOutputFile.dat'
    plot 'myInputFile.dat' u 1:3 with table
unset table
```

Write **row 1 and 3** into a new document: (row counting starts with 0). Check `help every`.

```
set datafile separator "\n"
set table 'myOutputFile.dat'
    plot 'myInputFile.dat' u (strcol(1)) every 2::0::2 with table
unset table
set datafile separator whitespace  # set it back in case you have some more data
```

Write the **sum of column 1 and 3** into a new document:

```
set table 'myOutputFile.dat'
    plot 'myInputFile.dat' u ($1+$3) with table
unset table
```